# JsonAPI resource Id recommendation

Tags: json, web-services, rest, api

[This](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-objects) page says that for a JSONAPI recommended type for "id" is string.

```
identification

Every resource object MUST contain an id member and a type member. The values of the id and type members MUST be strings.
```

What do we get from keeping it as string. In other words if for some case ids are only number, is it still recommended to keep them as string?

Answer (score 1):

They're not trying to cater for the 'some' cases. They're trying to put forward an API framework which allows clients to flexibly consume APIs. In particular, the idea is that if a client conforms to this specification, then it can start dealing with any API implementation which is also conformant. The key idea is portability. They're all about describing common characteristics between APIs.

Now, there aren't too many things you can *definitely* say about a resource, given that a resource is the thing which gives an API a purpose, but it's (perhaps) important to know which resource you've seen and what its type is. They're both pieces of information which any API consumer is going to need (the argument goes). Once you decide that they need to be common you need a common JSON datatype for them (because integers look different from strings in JSON).

The JSONAPI format is designed so that a single well-written client could actually process multiple different APIs with little or no alteration. It can only do that if it's able to distinguish between what's important for the client itself to process versus what's important for the client to pass on to a third party (e.g. stuff to display or manipulate in a UI).

Further on in the specification it talks about how type and id, taken together, form a namespace for any fields within the resource itself. So, for a client to use that information in any meaningful way it needs to know what the type of the id and type fields are.

Ultimately, the writers of the JSONAPI spec have said that the id and type fields are universally useful *regardless* of their value in the resource / API itself. As such, they both need to have reasonably well-defined semantics regardless of what makes sense for any individual API. Strings and integers behave differently so you need to make a choice. And Strings are a bit more flexible across APIs so they've made that call. They could probably have gotten away with choosing integers but they probably decided that it would be a bit restrictive in the cases where people really did want a String as an id.

Comment: Your answer make sense, I was more curious on why they used a "MUST be a string" in specification. It appears more like a mandate than a recommendation.